# Variable not defined in WITH clause

Tags: variables, neo4j, undefined, with-statement

In the following query

```
MATCH (i:UT)-[c:Cedes]->(r:UT) 
WHERE i.RiIndex=0
WITH r, c, i, (CASE WHEN i.gross > c.xs THEN i.gross-c.xs ELSE 0 END) AS mn
RETURN r, sum(c.pp*(mn)) AS  ceded
```

executes fine but

```
MATCH (i:UT)-[c:Cedes]->(r:UT) 
WHERE i.RiIndex=0
WITH r, c, i, (CASE WHEN i.gross > c.xs THEN i.gross-c.xs ELSE 0 END) AS mn, (CASE WHEN c.lim < mn THEN c.lim ELSE mn END) AS mx
RETURN r, sum(c.pp*(mx)) AS  ceded
```

gives the following error

```
Variable `mn` not defined (line 3, column 97 (offset: 146))
"WITH r, c, i, (CASE WHEN i.gross > c.xs THEN i.gross-c.xs ELSE 0 END) AS mn, (CASE WHEN c.lim < mn THEN c.lim ELSE mn END) AS mx"
                                                                                                 ^
```

Could someone advise if there's a way to pass the 'mn' variable through to the function creating the 'mx' variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WITH clause, `mn` is not yet in scope until the WITH clause is finished. You need another WITH afterwards that will have it in scope:

```
MATCH (i:UT)-[c:Cedes]->(r:UT) 
WHERE i.RiIndex=0
WITH r, c, i, (CASE WHEN i.gross > c.xs THEN i.gross-c.xs ELSE 0 END) AS mn
WITH r, c, i, (CASE WHEN c.lim < mn THEN c.lim ELSE mn END) AS mx
RETURN r, sum(c.pp*(mx)) AS  ceded
```